# How to allow a regular user to run a superuser command (from /usr/sbin)

Tags: permissions

Running Debian 9, I would like regular users to be able to run `alsactl monitor` as a trigger for repainting a status bar that shows the current volume - without having to resort to polling. However, `alsactl` lives in `/usr/sbin/`, in other words, needs superuser privileges. What is the best way to enable regular users to use this command?

To define *best*: a good compromise between *simple* and *restrictive*. In other words, using tools that ship with Debian or are available in the repositories, as well as not having to perform deep changes in the system is a plus, as is keeping the additional rights for the users as limited as possible.

<sub>**Note**: I found it incredibly hard to search for this issue, yet I'm almost certain very similar questions have been asked before. If you can point me to a suitable duplicate, I'll be more than happy to delete this.</sub>

Comment: Just because a program is in `/usr/sbin` doesn't necessarily mean it demands root privileges. Have you tried running it as an ordinary user, and if so what result (or error) do you get?

Comment: @roaima Good to know. However, I did try: `alsactl: command not found`

Comment: You may be able to execute your command using the full path `/usr/sbin/alsactl`.

Comment: @domsson that is simply because sbin dirs are not in regular user PATH variable. I am not 100% sure, but I rather think you still could run them by specifying the full path. Or by adding the appropriate dir to regular  users path.

Comment: @TimothyMartin and Gnudiff: That works! So simple - and somewhat obvious. Yet, it would've never occurred to me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to execute a command from `/usr/sbin` by using the absolute path to the command.

```
/usr/sbin/alsactl
```

You receive the message "alsactl: command not found" because `/usr/sbin` is not in the `PATH` of your non-superuser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sudoers rule inside /etc/sudoers file

```
joe ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/command args
```

in you case add a line like :

```
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/alsactl monitor
```

be carefull on giving too much permissions....
but I think alsactl isn't a command that needs sudo permissions

Comment: I assume this would require the users to run the command via sudo, so `sudo alsactl monitor`?

Comment: That's correct: probably `sudo /usr/sbin/alsactl monitor` actually. Or if you want, you can create an one-line script in /usr/local/bin that contains exactly that command, give it a nice descriptive name and set it executable. Since /usr/local/bin should be in the default `PATH` for regular users, this is how you can effectively create a new command for your users.